# C# program runs but then terminates?

Tags: c#

I'm using visual studios 2012 and I'm creating a program that prompts the user to enter the number of wheels their car has, the color of their car, the mileage etc.. and will display 'the starting point of the car, the mileage, and the color of the car once the user inputs their values. But, once I start the program and I enter the number of wheels, the program terminates and doesn't go to the next step.

```
public class Car
{

        private int NumbofWheels;
        private int Mileage;
        private String Color;
        private double point;
        private double newPoint;
        private String owner;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            Console.WriteLine("****************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("*           WELCOME TO CAR MANAGER     *");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("*             BY: MOHAMED SHIRE        *");
            Console.WriteLine("*                                      *");
            Console.WriteLine("*                                      *");
            Console.WriteLine("* **************************************");
            Console.Write("ENTER THE # OF WHEELS OF A CAR: ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public Car()
        {
            Mileage = 0;
            NumbofWheels = 4;
            point = 1000000;
        }

        public Car(int mile)
        {
            Mileage = mile;
        }

       public Car(int n, String c)
       {
           Mileage = 0;
           NumbofWheels = n;
           Color = c;
           point = 1000000;
       }

    public void setPoint( int p)
    {
        point = p;
    }

     public double getPoint()
    {
        return point;
    }
    public void setMileage(int m)
    {
        Mileage = m;

    }

    public int getMileage()
    {
        return Mileage;
    }

    public void setWheels(int w)
    {
        NumbofWheels = w;

    }

    public int getWheels()
    {

        return NumbofWheels;
    }

    public void setColor(String c)
    {
        Color = c;

    }

    public String getColor()
    {
        return Color;

    }
    public void setOwner(String o)
    {
        owner = o;
    }
    public String getOwner()
    {
        return owner;

    }

    public void calPoint()
    {
        newPoint = point - Mileage * 0.5;

    }
    public double getnPoint()
    {
        return newPoint;
    }



    }
}
```

'

Comment: What next step? You have no next step. You simply read the pressed key and exit the program.

Comment: May want to suggest to seperate your main program class and the actual Car class because cars normally dont have console inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all the code your program ever executes

```
        Console.WriteLine("****************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("*           WELCOME TO CAR MANAGER     *");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("*             BY: MOHAMED SHIRE        *");
        Console.WriteLine("*                                      *");
        Console.WriteLine("*                                      *");
        Console.WriteLine("* **************************************");
        Console.Write("ENTER THE # OF WHEELS OF A CAR: ");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

You define other classes and methods, but you never create an instance of another class and never call any class methods.

You want to figure out which key is actually pressed

```
var key = Console.ReadKey();
```

and then actually do something with `key`.

You want to convert `key` to an integer because methods of Car need an integer. There are three common ways to do that:

- int.Parse()
- Convert.ToInt32()
- int.TryParse()

Of those, [int.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you the best control because you can check whether the input could actually be converted to an integer without catching exceptions.

You will need to repeat your pattern of Console.Write() and Console.ReadKey() to get the additional input you need, then create an instance of Car to pass that input on to.

Comment: Ahh...I found my mistake, I need to create another class lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the last setp you programmed. You'll have to call functions after you read the nr... **example**

```
console.Readkey();
doSomethingWithNr();
```

Answer (score -1):

what you're looking for is 
Console.ReadLine()

Comment: C# is case sensitive

Comment: The program will still terminate if you use Console.ReadLine()

Comment: You mean 'NumofWheels = Conver.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());' ? Would I also have to do this for the color, the miles, owners name also? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment